# How to make these web services work, man in middle is KEMP too

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, sharepoint

I have a custom WCF service hosted in SharePoint 2013 with following configuration,

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="my_BasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="NTLM" />
      </security>
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

with client side code as,

```
            System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential("UserName ", "password", "domain");

            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;//.Windows;

            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://example.portal.com + "/_vti_bin/MyServiceFolder/MyService.svc");
            ChannelFactory<MyType> factory = new ChannelFactory<MyType>(binding, endpoint);
            factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = creds.UserName;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = creds.Password;
            factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            //factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
            MyType proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            string result = proxy.MyMethod();
```

I change it to Windows then I get this,

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

and If I change it to NTLM...

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'NTLM'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

and if I remove negotiate from web application's window's authentication's providers... I get this,

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.