# Why web services call only succeeds when pre logined through browser atleast once a day on server

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, binding, sharepoint-2013

I have following bindings on server side,

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="my_BasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

and client code running in console on same server,

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential("UserName ", "password", "domain");

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows; //.Ntlm; // Basic;

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://example.portal.com + "/_vti_bin/MyServiceFolder/MyService.svc");
ChannelFactory<MyType> factory = new ChannelFactory<MyType>(binding, endpoint);
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = creds.UserName;
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = creds.Password;
//factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
//factory.Credentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
MyType proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

string result = proxy.MyMethod();
```

Now it usually throws 401 but when I login through browser using same username to view .svc file and try this code again... IT WORKS. BUT again next morning it won't work till I repeat the steps.

Some more details can be found here but with different settings and scenario -
[How to make these web services work, man in middle is KEMP too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779066/how-to-make-these-web-services-work-man-in-middle-is-kemp-too)

Could it be related to SharePoint or authentication protocols or the way Kerborse works etc.. got no clue ?

Comment: do you have access to MyService.svc logic ?

Comment: yes I do, but I don't see it's playing a big role here :)

Comment: you mentioned sharepoint so i wanted to make sure its a custom endpoint